# Is there a Java quivalent to C#'s "new static" or "static new"?

Tags: java

Is there a Java quivalent to C#'s [new Modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. In the case of static methods, they're not inherited in Java, so you don't need an equivalent of the new modifier.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no similar construct in Java.**

(Do not confuse `new` with the opposite of `@Override`. It is not.)

Consider this C# code:

```
class A {
    virtual public int x() { return 1; }
    virtual public int y() { return 1; }
}

class B : A {
    new public int x() { return 2; }
    override public int y() { return 2; }
}

void Main()
{
    A aa = new A();
    A ba = new B(); // compile time type of ba is A
    B bb = new B(); // compile time type of bb is B

    aa.x().Dump();
    ba.x().Dump(); // look how this is really A.x!!
    bb.x().Dump();

    "---".Dump();

    aa.y().Dump();
    ba.y().Dump(); // this is B.y!
    bb.y().Dump();
}
```

When run in LINQPad this generates:

```
1
1
2
---
1
2
2
```

Note how the *compile time type* determines which method is called and this is influenced by using either the `new` or `override` modifier. The `new` modifier essentially *introduces a fork determined by compile-time type* for the given member. It can be used for great power ... and with great power comes more clichés.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

No.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html

You could do this with an [APT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html)-based toolchain.  Define an annotation, and detect cases of field hiding without annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface HideSuper { }
```

and then in your code

```
public class Parent {
   Object x;
}

public class GoodChild extends Parent {
   @HideSuper Object x; 
}

public class TroublingChild extends Parent {
   Object x; // your plugin should raise warnings here
}
```

[post answer edit]:

1 - Note that while the mentioned `@Override` has close semantics to `new`, it can not be uniformly applied to class *members*.

2 - Regarding suggestion above, it is arguably more correct to reduced the scope of the retention to `Class` or perhaps even `Source`.

3 - Finally, APT based approaches should be supported by your IDE. Eclipse supports it in a fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the equivalent you're looking for might be the @Override annotation.  It provides the compiler with a hint that you intended to override a method from the parent.  All methods in Java objects are "virtual" like you have to define in C++ and can be overridden for polymorphic behavior.

```
public class Car {
    public void start() { ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Ferrari {
    @Override
    public void start() {
    }
}
```

With @Override, the compiler will then give errors if you change the Car.start() signature and don't change the Ferrari.start() to match.

Comment: Ok, so reading the C# docs a bit further, the answer is both yes and no.  Yes for methods, no for statics (as Steve Taylor says).

Comment: `@Override` isn't the same at all. In a very general sense it is the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't.

In Java, a subclass will either override or hide superclass members (fields, methods, types) of the same name. Hiding never emits a warning, so there is no need for a modifier to suppress the warning.